# Regex - Get only decimal number from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex below:

```
(?<=Bonus)[\s+][\$][\s+]?(\d(?:[d{0,2}.\s]*\d)?)
```

This gets the expected outcomes, however, sometimes I also get one extra digit.

For example, this is the context:

```
Bonus $0. 01 87% 88% 89% 90% 92% 93% 94%
```

So my regex gets 0 . 01 just fine, but not every time.
When there are more lines like below:

```
Bonus $0. 01 87% 88% 89% 90% 92% 93% 94%
...
Bonus $0. 11 87% 88% 89% 90% 92% 93% 94%
...
Bonus $0. 15 87% 88% 89% 90% 92% 93% 94%
...
```

sometimes it gets one extra digit from string:

```
0. 01
0. 11 8
0. 15
```

OR sometimes miss 1 decimal place:

```
0. 1 (but it should be 0. 15)
```

Expected outcome will be always a number with 2 decimal places. There may or may not be whitespace(s) in numbers. Could be like 0.01, 0. 01, or even 0.(more whitespaces) 01...

What's wrong with my current regex?

Comment: Try: `(?:Bonus \$)(\d+\.(.\d+|\d+))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That matches everything correctly:
`(?<=Bonus)[\s+][\$][\s+]?(\d*\.\s*\d{2}?)`

Answer (score 1):

If you capture the digits in a group, you don't need a lookbehind for Bonus, you can match it instead.

**Note** that in your pattern, this part is a character class `[d{0,2}.\s]` that matches any of the listed chars, including a `d` char.

You could also omit the superfluous square brackets.

---

To match only digits with a decimal part (which seem to be always 2 digits):

```
\bBonus\s+\$\s*(\d+\.\s*\d{2})\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bBonus\s+\$\s*` Match Bonus, 1+ whitespace chars, `$` char and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+\.\s*\d{2}` Match 1+ digits, a dot, optional whitespace chars and 2 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S0bwwY/1)

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many character classes, in particular this one: `[d{0,2}.\s]` - you can't quantify things inside a character class, so this isn't doing what it should be doing. (you can also get rid of some other ones, like `\s+` instead of `[\s+]`)

If I understand correctly that you want to match 2 digits after the decimal, spaces being possibly interspersed, this might work:

```
(?<=Bonus)\s*\$\s*\d*\.(\s*\d\s*){0,2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/nDj8Gd/1/